# What is the best way to achieve SSO for Apache 2.4 within a Windows domain?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ldap, kerberos, gssapi

I would like to implement an SSO authentication (without login/password prompt) on a PHP 8 intranet app, which runs under Apache 2.4 x64 for Windows. My company has an Active Directory / LDAP / Windows environment.

I managed to do this via the Apache **mod_authn_ntml** ([NTLM module for Windows](https://github.com/TQsoft-GmbH/mod_authn_ntlm)) and also via the SSPI module (**mod_authnz_sspi**, formerly available on ApacheHaus). I am then able to get the variables `$_SERVER ['REMOTE_USER']` or `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` without problem.

In the meantime, I read that NTLM was phased out and would therefore like to find a more suitable technology.
The SSPI module does indeed seem to rely (only?) on NTLM.

Can you tell me if it would be possible to use a negotiate mode which would itself rely on LDAP or Kerberos authentication with the SSPI module that I am using? There is no doc available unfortunately.

Would this type of transparent authentication (without prompt for credentials) could eventually be achieved with the Apache native module **mod_authnz_ldap**?

I have looked at **mod_auth_kerb** but there is not available module for Windows and the **GSSAPI** does not seem to be intended for Windows either.

Comment: PHP 8 end of life? Where do you see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSPI is generic Windows interface to both Kerberos and NTLM; it's the Microsoft equivalent of GSSAPI. A module that uses SSPI should accept both mechanisms – though it's up to the client to decide what is actually offered when it sees the `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate`.

Keep in mind that Kerberos requires the server to have its own Kerberos identity (the Service Principal) – and HTTP Negotiate auth doesn't have any means for a server to indicate "I only accept Kerberos" upfront – so a Windows client that is unable to obtain a Kerberos ticket for the service will automatically fall back to sending an NTLM token instead.

So my bet is that your conclusion that "The SSPI module does indeed seem to rely (only?) on NTLM" is based on incomplete configuration, and the SSPI module is what you should be using regardless.

Meanwhile, LDAP is **not** an SSO mechanism. It's the user account *database*, which also happens to have the ability to validate raw passwords, but it does not have any SSO mechanisms the way Kerberos or OAuth do – you can use it for authorization, but trying to use it for authentication will inevitably result in a password prompt.

---

I would generally not host Apache on Windows at all (did that, learned the lesson).

Comment: You're right about the fact that it's the configuration that will make the choice between Kerberos or a cascade to NTML. I wanted to be sure that the SSPI module for Apache could handle both methods without having to add an additional module. Good news, it seems to be the case according to your answer. So I'm going to test triggering the Kerberos method via a Firefox config (NTLM is disabled in FF in my company). Thanks a lot.